# Angular 4 Changes based on view

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-animation

I have a div which is like

```
 <div [ngClass]="{'active' : isActive} [ngStyle]={top: topVar } >
```

isActive and topVar are calculated based on the view, (like if the content overflowed, and the content is dynamic).

***so I calculate them in ngAfterViewChecked.***

which ofcourse gives me this error :

```
Expression has changed after it was checked, previous value : "undefined". current value : '636px'.
```

I understand what I did wrong, my question is, how to do it right?

(If I calculate the the vars based on the component view, I need ngAfterViewChecked --> I need to detectChanged again,
and if I will make ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() everytime --> i will enter a loop. --> I need a condition to stop it.   that feels hacky and wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your the code into setTimeout function. Like

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  setTimeout({...calculation});
}
```

Comment: Well, isn't the same like calling detection?

Comment: the error indicates that u can't do the operation that affects model to be performed in live cycle methods. with Timeout you just move it to the next tick and angular won't complain about it.

Comment: I just found it the setTimeout makes my e2e tests fails ! ,  - "Failed: Timed out waitig for asynchronous angular tasks to finish..... -  this may be because the current page is not angular application",  if I remove the timeout it works great.

Comment: Furthermore, I just found out setTimeout refresh the all application tree, which is less efficient.  Any other ways?

Comment: Can the component's parent calculate isActive and topVar and pass them to the child?