# Angular 2 setTimeout e2e tests fails

Tags: angular, protractor

I have a component which calculate properties in the "afterViewChecked" lifeCycle,  so I need to use setTimeout - for the changes to apply or else I get errors.  ([Angular 4 Changes based on view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653504/angular-4-changes-based-on-view))

I just found out that setTimeout, **no matter where in my application** causing protractor to throw timeout message. - which says

> Failed: Timed out waitig for asynchronous angular tasks to finish..... - this may be because the current page is not angular application",

What should I do?  - sometimes you just need to use setTimeout...

Comment: You need a way to fire a function once the DOM elements have been rendered?

Comment: Well yeah, after the items has been rendered, I need to calculate some dom properties and if they met the condition - to fire a function.     an other place in my app that there is timeout is on startup, but it's temporary.  if I remove those 2 timeouts, tests works.

Comment: Ok. The intention with your `setTimout` was to fire a function once the elements are rendered? Would another method be ok, in order to avoid the `setTimeout`-problem? Another way of checking if rendered.

Comment: Well I can't think of an other way, I can call markForDetection maybe but I'm afraid there might be a case of infinite loop or something.

Comment: I've put together an example in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way of detecting DOM changes is via [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Instantiate the class in the constructor, where you define what to do on a change, and then observe it in `ngAfterViewInit()`. When you run the calculation function you want, you can then stop observing so that the function won't keep firing if further changes occur.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `<div #element></div>`
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ContentChild('element') element : ElementRef;
  this.observer: MutationObserver;

  constructor() {
    this.observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      this.testFunction();
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.observer.observe(this.element.nativeElement, { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true });
  }

  testFunction() {
    this.observer.disconnect(); // We no longer want to observe
    alert('Test!');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace $timeout with $interval and it will work.
"If your page uses $timeout for polling Protractor will not be able to tell when your page is ready. Consider using $interval instead of $timeout."

Their official docs: http://www.protractortest.org/#/system-setup
https://github.com/marcorinck/angular-growl/issues/43